# Using excel-builder inline in a document

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using [excel-builder](http://excelbuilderjs.com/index.html) to generate an excel file, but couldn't manage to put it to work. The reason for this is that I need all my source in the same file, I cannot use other files and excel-builder uses[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org). I have also never used RequireJS before.

According to the docs, here's how to create a workbook with excel-builder:

```
require(['excel-builder/Excel/Workbook'], function (Workbook) {
    var workbook = new Workbook();
});
```

What I did was copy+paste the excel-builder code from the excel-builder.compiled.min.js file, which seems to already include the dependencies. After that I place my code, but the problem is that nothing happens.

```
require(['excel-builder/Excel/Workbook'], function() {
    console.log('here');
});
```

I don't even get an error. How can I use this module like this?

Comment: do you need excel features, or just to move data? if just data, there are much simpler ways of creating excel documents; TSV/CSV and html tables saved as sheet1.xls come to mind.

Comment: Not really, just the data. I though of using CSV, but decided to give XLS/XLSX a try. But it does seem that I'll use that fallback after all.